# Как запустить чат (node.js, socket.io) на сайте?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Пробую запустить чат из примера на сайте [SOCKET.IO](http://socket.io/).

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');

console.log('a user connected');
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('user disconnected');
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
io.emit('chat message', msg);
console.log('message: ' + msg);
});
});
```

запускаю:
node server.js &

```
netstat -lnp -t
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:3000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 9429/node
```

на сколько я понимаю - всё нормально, 3000 порт прослушивается.

пробую из браузера:
`mydomen.com:3000`
- **не загружается**.

на хосте - Услуга: *Виртуальный сервер / OpenVZ*

Где что ни так? Поверьте - перелопатил десятки скриптов, убил 2 дня не пойму в чем дело - у всех работает, у меня нет.

Comment: Естественно, там же в коде нигде не фигурирует "отдавать страницу с чатом". Вы понимаете, что у вас в коде написано? Нет? А стоит почитать.

Comment: да я уже вобще мало что понимаю!
брал пример с https://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/
грузится оч долго, сообщения не отсылаются

Comment: Потому что вместо того, чтобы слепо копировать примеры, их стоит разбирать :)

Comment: Довольно-таки поучительно. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Держи собранный пример (все с офф сайта socket.io)  [Скачать](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxyAE95fx87WHVfWTV0aW5tcDA)